# Is there any source that explains ";" in R?

Tags: r

I just started to learn R. I found that semicolon can separate multiple statements in the same line, but I couldn't find a source to confirm this. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Try the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Control-structures)